# Resource Not Found Exception while integrating AdMob

Tags: android, admob

Android 2.3.3

I have followed the steps, found in the [this](http://manijshrestha.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/integrating-admob-in-your-android-app-and-make-money/) tutorial. When I run the application in my device(mobile), the ads are getting displayed. No Problem here. But when I try to view the activity in my eclipse, I get a blank screen with the NullPointerException. I have taken the screenshot. Please refer to it.

[image]

Then, I have clicked on the link, given in the exception's "detail" (SourceFile:670) and I get the following details..

[image]

I have clicked on the Add Source, and browsed to the jar file in my application->libs folder. Then I get the following...

[image]

Here are my xml and java codes that I have used...

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         ads:adUnitId="a151xxxxxxxxx"
                         ads:adSize="BANNER"
                         ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtViewPrevious"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:height="25dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="16sp" />

.....
.....
```

Java

```
private AdView adView;
adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Libs

[image]

How do i get rid of these exceptions?

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Download](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/download) the latest SDK. Per the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/rel-notes), this was fixed in v6.3.0.

Answer (score 1):

This happens. It's normal. Eclipse can't display custom views sometimes (most of the time actually).